# Python Tkinter variables not being reevaluated

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I am just learning the TKinter module for Python and have a simple text box that asks for speed and time and prints distance. For some reason my distance is always whatever the speed is initialized as times what ever I input as time. I think I either need a second entry or to globalize my variables but I was wondering what you

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
speed = 10; time = 10; d = 50
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
e. delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, "Enter Speed")

def callspeed():
        s = e.get()    
        speed = int(s)
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, "Enter time")

def calltime():
        t = e.get()
        time = int(t)
        d = speed * time
        print d

bs = Button(master, text="Speed", width=15, command=callspeed)
bs.pack()
bt = Button(master, text="Time", width=15, command=calltime)
bt.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this line in `callspeed`:

```
speed = int(s)
```

Creates a new *local* variable called `speed`, instead of updating the global variable.

To fix it, you just need a [`global`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) declaration:

```
def callspeed():
    global speed
    s = e.get()    
    speed = int(s)
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, "Enter time")
```

The exact rules are a bit complicated ("free variables"—which basically means variables you reference but never assign to—can come either from a closure or from globals; variables you assign to are always local), but the safe thing to do is to always add a `global` statement when you want to use a global variable.

---

Or, even safer, don't use global variables in the first place.

For example, you could move all of this code, or just the "model" part of it, into a class, and make `speed` an instance variable.

```
class ThingyModel(object):
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.speed, self.time, self.d = 10, 10, 50
        self.e = e

    def callspeed(self):
        s = self.e.get()
        self.speed = int(s)
        self.e.delete(0, END)
        self.e.insert(0, "Enter time")

    def calltime(self):
        t = self.e.get()
        self.time = int(t)
        self.d = self.speed * self.time
        print d

e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
e. delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, "Enter Speed")

model = ThingyModel(e)

bs = Button(master, text="Speed", width=15, command=model.callspeed)
bs.pack()
bt = Button(master, text="Time", width=15, command=model.calltime)
bt.pack()
```

(This isn't a real MVC design, because the "controller" part is scattered all over, and the "view" isn't organized into any kind of structure, but it should be enough to show the basic idea.)

Comment: +1 But I feel like I should mention it's common to see Tkinter classes inheriting from something like `Tkinter.Frame` where the widget logic is kept inside and only an instance of `Tkinter.Tk()` is passed to `__init__`.

Comment: @Jared: Yes, I started doing a pythonic/tkinteric cleanup of the whole thing, to show both an MVC design and a traditional Tkinter "smart view" design… but then I decided that was getting way off track. Your comment is a good pointer without needing a big example.

Answer (score 0):

abarnert is right, global variables are messy. Here's my rewrite with speed and time as local variables:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
Label(master,text="Speed:").grid(row=0,column=0)
Label(master,text="Time:").grid(row=1,column=0)
speed_entry = Entry(master)
speed_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
time_entry = Entry(master)
time_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)

def submit():
    speed = float(speed_entry.get())
    time = float(time_entry.get())
    print "Speed is",speed
    print "Time is", time
    print "Distance is",speed*time

Button(master,text="Submit",command=submit).grid()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is probably a better UI and a better design than the OP's… but it's not really equivalent to the OP's, and doesn't show how to solve the problem of needing state that persists between two functions—which is a problem that most real GUIs do need to solve.